# How to add SXA license to Sitecore instance?

Tags: sxa

I am newbie to Sitecore. I have Sitecore Experience Platform running on my development machine. I need to set up Sitecore Experience Accelerator for this instance.

I have installed required packages for it. The problem is that I have got license file but I am not sure where that has to be placed.

Can anyone guide me to place this file in proper location?

Comment: ~/App_Data, relative to your webroot

Comment: Hi user5955 and welcome to the Sitecore Stack Exchange. In a typical Sitecore installation, a single file called "license.xml" is used when installing the product. This file is where Sitecore can add additional products (such as SXA and JSS). When you use the license Sitecore can detect whether or not you are properly licensed. Just use whatever file was provided to you and it will probably work. As Mark mentioned, depending on your version it could appear in 1 of 2 places. Specifying the license file is typically required at the time of installation of Sitecore (not SXA).

Comment: Yes, got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to replace the existing `license.xml` with the new one.

Up to Sitecore 8 version the Sitecore license file is located only in the `/Data` folder. But Sitecore 9 onwards, you'll need to replace at below locations:

- **Sitecore client website folder**  -> <Path_to_sitecore_instance>\App_Data
- **Sitecore XConnect website folder** -> <Path_to_sitecore_XConnect instance>\App_data
- **Index worker** -> <Path_to_sitecore_XConnect_instance>\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data
- **Automation Engine** -> <Path_to_sitecore_XConnect_instance>\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data
- **Processing Engine** ->  <Path_to_sitecore_XConnect_instance>\App_data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine\App_Data
- **Identity Server** --> <Path_to_sitecore_identity_server_instance>\sitecoreruntime

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Sitecore version you are using, by **default**, Sitecore stores the license file in

```
Sitecore Versions up to 8.* -> Data Folder just outside the website folder
```

[image]

```
Sitecore Versions 9.* -> App_Data
```

[image]

Now, it is also possible that you have a config patch that has updated the Data Folder path. By doing a `showconfig.aspx (http://yourdomain/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx)`, search for `name="dataFolder"` and it will show you where the Data folder is.

**Note**

You'll need to overwrite the existing `license.xml` file with the new one

Comment: Yes, I do have a license.xml file in Data folder since i am having Sitecore XP 8.2. I am trying to set up SXA for this sitecore instance. Could you please guide me for SXA, where do i need to place the license file?

Comment: Just replace the license file found in the Data Folder with the one you got for sxa

Comment: I replaced the license file as you suggested and that worked. Thanks a lot! @Hishaam Namooya